# Zend Framework 2 Console Routes

Tags: php, console, zend-framework2

I'm trying to define some console routes for my ZF2 application as described here http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.console.routes.html

in the module config I have:

```
'console' => array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'user-set-password' => array(
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => 'user password <username> <password>',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'User\Profile',
                        'action' => 'setpassword'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

but it seems to never match the route as it always prints the usage information. also simple routes like just 'test' won't be matched.
(when I write some crap into the route parameter, the execution fails with an `Zend\Mvc\Router\Exception\InvalidArgumentException` so it recognizes the console route when loading the module)

is it my fault or maybe a bug in the latest zf2 version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just found the solution in an inconsistent interface for the route definitions:

it works if you provide the following schema for the controller:

```
'controller' => 'User\Controller\Profile'
```

would be better to be able to define it in the same way as http routes:

```
'defaults' => array(
    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'User\Controller',
    'controller' => 'Profile',
    'action' => 'setpassword',
),
```

just opened an issue for that: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-515